# Look up data in a column based on a value in another column, same row

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, lookup

I have a dataframe that has 6 columns (A-F) and over 200K rows. I would like to look up a string in a column B (named word), and find its corresponding value in another column D(tf value), same row, please.

For example I want the output to be:

Word: encryption, tf: 0.009041.

I rather not use a loop, but if needed I am open to suggestions, as the df is large.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). (2) Your description of how to select the row is not clear, please elaborate. For some guidance on how to well ask your question, please scan through one or more of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I edited the question to better reflect my inquiry, and removed the image from my own dataframe.

Comment: I think you missed one of the salient points, Shawn. An image of data is bad. No data at all is worse. *"I need my dataframe to be transformed from <nothing-provided> to <this>"* is not a good way to solicit help. ***Please*** read the links I provided; they are not my being lazy or snotty, those happen to be succinct and well-accepted norms for how to ask well your question and improve the likelihood of getting a relevant answer, more quickly. In the future, your change of getting a good answer is high if you do it all the first time, while it's still "new" on the list of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that I don't understand the question, but is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
tf <- yourdata %>%
    filter(Word == 'encryption') %>%
    select(tf)
```

That would create a data frame containing only the column tf and only rows for which the value of Word is 'encryption'. If you wanted the rows containing any one of a set of words in either the columns Class or Word, you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
wordset <- c('hockey','encryption')
tf <- yourdata %>%
    filter(Class %in% wordset | Word %in% wordset) %>%
    select(tf)
```

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly.  Thank you very much for your assistance.